# Page Refresh and Counter Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, refresh

I have a web page which, on page load, initializes a counter to 0.  On every postback, the counter, which is saved in a session, is incremented by 1 until it reaches a value of 4.  Basically, the idea behind this is that the user is given 4 chances to enter a username and the CAPTCHA image displayed on screen.  If the user fails for 4 times (thus the use of the counter), he is redirected to an error page.

This is the code in my page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Label_Error.Visible = false;
        Session["Count"] = 0;
    }

    else
    {
        if (Session["Count"] == null)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
        }

        else
        {
            int count = (int)Session["Count"];
            count++;
            Session["Count"] = count;
        }
    }
}
```

The check for count == 4 is being done when the button is clicked.  Now the code works fine.  If the user clicks on the button for 4 times, he is not allowed anymore.  The only problem crops up if the user hits the refresh button.  As a matter of fact, once the user hits refresh, the counter is set to 0 and he has another 4 attempts.  How can I stop this from happening?  I don't want the counter to be set to 0 on page refresh.  I want the counter's value to remain as it is.  How can I do this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem fundamentally is this segment:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    Label_Error.Visible = false;
    Session["Count"] = 0;
}
```

If you were to check whether the session variable existed first, rather than overwriting the value automatically, that may solve your problem:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    Label_Error.Visible = false;
    Session["Count"] = Session["Count"] ?? 0;
}
```

Of course, that does assume that the user doesn't clear out their cookies and start a new session.

Comment: That is true. It appears that every time the page is refreshed, it is calling that statement of code, thus resetting the counter.

Comment: What does this part of the code mean please? Session["Count"] ?? 0;

Comment: @Matthew It's called the "null coalescing operator"; if the value of the left-hand side is null it returns the right-hand side. It's one of those bits of syntax that's very difficult to Google for!

Comment: So it is equivalent to if(Session["Count"] = null) {Session["Count"] = 0}?  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Pretty much identical, yes (to your second example, not the first). Take a quick look at MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx.

Comment: Additional useless trivia: Groovy has a version of this, but there it's `?:` and is referred to as the Elvis operator.

Comment: Thank you so much Adrain Wragg :)  I can confirm that it is working great :)  Thank you so much :)